# Assigning list elements to variables

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, variable-assignment

The output from Mathematica with the following operation `FactorInteger[28851680048402838857]` is as follows:

```
{{3897424303, 1}, {7402755719, 1}}
```

My question is: how could I go about extracting the two prime numbers (without the exponents) and assign them to an arbitrary variable?

I basically want to retrieve two primes, whatever they may be, and assign them some variables.

Ex: `x0 = 3897424303` and `x1 = 7402755719`

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The output is a list and you can use [list manipulating functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListManipulation.html) like [`Part` ([[  ]])](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) to pick the pieces you want, e.g.,

```
{x0, x1} = FactorInteger[28851680048402838857][[All, 1]]
```

or, without `Part`:

```
{{x0,dummy}, {x1,dummy}} = FactorInteger[28851680048402838857];
```

Comment: First /@ FactorInteger[28851680048402838857] is another option

Comment: @Michael It's nothing, really.

Answer (score 4):

Implicit in your question is the issue of handing parts of the expression that is returned as output from functions such as `FactorInteger`.  Allow me to suggest alternatives.

#### 1. Keep all of the values in a `{list}` and access each element with [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html):

```
x = First /@ FactorInteger[7813426]
```

```
{2, 31, 126023}
```

```
x[[1]]
x[[3]]
```

```
2
```

```
126023
```

#### 2. Store factors as values of the *function* `x`, mimicking indexation of an array:

(This code uses [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapIndexed.html), [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html).)

```
Clear[x]

MapIndexed[
  (x[First@#2] = First@#1) &,
  FactorInteger[7813426]
];

x[1]
x[3]
```

```
2
```

```
126023
```

You can see all the values using `?` or `??` (see [`Information`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Information.html)):

```
?x
```

```
Global`x

x[1]=2

x[2]=31

x[3]=126023
```

Comment: I thought that the word indexing is usually applied in the context of arrays. You are now using it to mean function arguments. I feel that may confuse some.

Comment: @Sjoerd I thought I was using it right: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html  Do I misunderstand that page?

Comment: Please note that this page has the words arrays and index between double quotes, indicating that the author is aware that this is an abuse of existing jargon. I think you know just as well that this is not the conventional way of using these words. We often see mma starters using a[i] instead of a[[i]] because mma is a bit uncoventianal in this sense. Better not add to this confusion.

Comment: @Sjoerd, please edit this answer as you see fit.  I honestly don't know what I should write.  I am poor with terminology.

Comment: I apologize, it was not my intention to play language nazi. But thought it wiser, given the level of the question, to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @Sjoerd, it is perfectly fine that you point out the mistake, but please, also correct it now.  :-)

Comment: @Sjoerd I'll defer to others on this.